# finding the orientation of curves such that sum of winding indices is 0

Tags: complex-analysis

Let B± = B¯(±1; 1/2
), G = B(0; 3)−(B+∪B−). Let γ1, γ2, γ3 be curves whose traces are |z−1| = 1,
|z+1| = 1, and |z| = 2, respectively. Give γ1, γ2, and γ3 orientations such that n(γ1;w)+n(γ2;w)+n(γ3;w) =
0 for all w in C − G.
this is a problem from conway . i was thinking og taking a point in C − G and think , how many times the curves wind about the point. is it like that?